# how to avoid bidirectional relationship in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, data-warehouse, ssas-tabular

seeking help to tune my Power BI report !

Below is the link to understand my question in a better way.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yXug0FhTxguZTOFIIkInJk5rfXyF0YjggUdxpKCd4FQ/edit?usp=sharing

Below is the link to understand data model.
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvZUqpXgHxIVzR7qBZRlOpMpcsHR?e=uwin7v

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: You need to have your question in your post, not linked to an external site.

Comment: what are the reasons for the bridge table? can you provide a small data sample that illustrates the need for it?

Comment: Hi @RADO

FactPrescriptionProjection contains doctor's prescription records and a doctor can prescribe  multiple medicine. That's why we created another table to store medicine's record with 'FactPrescriptionProjection'[FactPrescriptionProjectionID].

Please find attched sample file.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvZUqpXgHxIVzR87nuZuZngndT54?e=wboViJ